# How to set a common title for all the axes in a column of subfigures?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to set a common title for the axes of the same column.

In the example below, we should have the ids titles only once and they should be placed at the very top of each column.

I can't figure it out. Can you guys show me how to do that ?

[image]

Here is my code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

categories = ["category1", "category2", "category3"]
ids = ["id1", "id2"]

data = [
    [{"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3}, {"D": 4, "E": 5, "F": 6}],
    [{"G": 7, "H": 8, "I": 9}, {"J": 10, "K": 11, "L": 12}],
    [{"M": 13, "N": 14, "O": 15}, {"P": 16, "Q": 17, "R": 18}],
]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 6))

subfigs = fig.subfigures(len(categories), 1)

for category, subfig, data_row in zip(categories, subfigs.flat, data):
    _ = subfig.supylabel(t=category, x=0.09)
    axs = subfig.subplots(1, len(ids))

    for id, ax, data_dict in zip(ids, axs.flat, data_row):
        _ = ax.set(title=id)
        _ = ax.bar(data_dict.keys(), data_dict.values())

plt.show()
```

Comment: That's quite a complicated way of doing a subplot, would you be okay if I change it?

Answer (score 1):

I redid your suplotting, you could have done it much simpler:

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
categories = ["category1", "category2", "category3"]
ids = ["id1", "id2"]
data = [
    [{"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3}, {"D": 4, "E": 5, "F": 6}],
    [{"G": 7, "H": 8, "I": 9}, {"J": 10, "K": 11, "L": 12}],
    [{"M": 13, "N": 14, "O": 15}, {"P": 16, "Q": 17, "R": 18}],
]
fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(categories), len(ids), figsize=(8, 4)) # define the subplot
fig.suptitle('Common X-axis Title', fontsize=12) # define the title of the subplots
for i, category in enumerate(categories): # for every category
    axs[i, 0].set_ylabel(category, rotation=0, ha='right', va='center') # set ylabel of categories
    for j, (eachID, data_dict) in enumerate(zip(ids, data[i])): # loop through the data and the number of rows
        if i == 0: # if we are on the first row
            axs[i, j].set_title(eachID) # set the title only if we are on the first row
        axs[i, j].bar(data_dict.keys(), data_dict.values()) # add the bar with the data
plt.tight_layout() # tight layout, or if you want you can remove it
plt.show() #
```

Here, I also only specify the title of the subplot if it is on the first row, giving the optical illusion that it is defined for all subplots in one column. If this is not fine for you, then please let me know, so I can figure something else out.

Comment: Subplots is what I'd use here as well!

Comment: @SamMason it would take some hard reasons to justify subfigures, in my opinion...

Answer (score 1):

Given your original code, the only thing you need to change is to ensure that you add the title only once at the first row of each column.

This can be done by enumerating in the outer loop, and changing the inner loop to check that the row index is equal to `0`, see `if i == 0` below:

```
for i, (category, subfig, data_row) in enumerate(zip(categories, subfigs.flat, data)):
    
    # ...
    # same code

    for id, ax, data_dict in zip(ids, axs.flat, data_row):
        # Check to ensure that the id title is added only once
        # in the first row of each column
        if i == 0:  
            ax.set(title=id)
        _ = ax.bar(data_dict.keys(), data_dict.values())
```

Which results in the following figure:

[image]

Also, as highlighted in the comment, `id` is reserved in python for the build-in function `id()`, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id). Therefore, it is not recommended to use it as a variable. You could change `id` to `_id` for instance.

Comment: OP has no `i` in his code. Also, it would be much better if you avoid using `id` as a variable name, since it is a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `plt.subplots` and then add the titles after you've plotted the data. This is simple to do since the axes returned by `plt.subplots` is a numpy `ndarray` where the first row is the top row.

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 2)

# plotting code

for i, ax in enumerate(axes[0], start=1):
    ax.set_title(f"id{i}")
```

[image]